# Timing commands within one slide

Tags: beamer, pdf, transition

The commands \transduration{time}\effect (e.g. \transduration{10}\transfade) is used to automatically play slides and elements within a slide. Yet it seems that the parameter "time" has to be constant within one slide. Is it possible to make different times for different elements that appear on one slide? (e.g. items in a list depending on their length)?

For example,

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate} 
\item This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a   long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. \pause
\item This is a short item. This is a short item. \pause
\item This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. \pause
\item This is a short item. This is a short item. \pause

\end{enumerate}
\transduration{2}\transfade
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please provide minimal code we can compile as an example i.e. a small document demonstrating the effect you are asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but not automatically. Since `\transduration` is overlay aware, you can do something like

```
\transduration<1>{10}
\transduration<2>{2}
\transduration<3>{10}
\transduration<4>{2}
```

notice also the `[<+->]` overlay specification for `enumerate` so you don't have to manually introduce `\pause`s:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a   long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item.
\item This is a short item. This is a short item.
\item This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item. This is a long item.
\item This is a short item. This is a short item.
\end{enumerate}
\transduration<1>{10}
\transduration<2>{2}
\transduration<3>{10}
\transduration<4>{2}
\transfade
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```